# Unrecognized option access_token under security.firewalls.main

Tags: symfony

I've switched recently to Symfony 6.2 and want to use the newly introduces `AccessTokenHandler` for Bearer Authentication.

So all the cache is cleared after updating and I'm following the guide at https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_token.html.

This is part of my security.yaml:

```
security:
       firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            access_token:
                token_handler: App\Security\AccessTokenHandler
                token_extractors: header
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

But when I make some requests to my page, it says

> Unrecognized option "access_token" under "security.firewalls.main".
> Available options are "access_denied_handler", "access_denied_url",
> "context", "custom_authenticators", "entry_point", "form_login",
> "form_login_ldap", "host", "http_basic", "http_basic_ldap",
> "json_login", "json_login_ldap", "lazy", "login_link",
> "login_throttling", "logout", "methods", "pattern", "provider",
> "remember_me", "remote_user", "request_matcher", "required_badges",
> "security", "stateless", "switch_user", "user_checker", "x509".

So this looks like the changes to symfony 6.2 are not working. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not yet, I've postponed this topic for a while and check back with the next symfony patches.

Comment: Are you sure you are running symfony 6.2 and updated it (and its subpackages) through composer? I ran into this issue because my app was running still on 6.1. This feature requires 6.2.*